# How should I be storing objects that I wish to access in reverse order of the way I placed them in

Tags: java, maze

I'm following this guide here: http://www.mazeworks.com/mazegen/mazetut/index.htm

Or more specficially

> ```
> create a CellStack (LIFO) to hold a list of cell locations 
> set TotalCells = number of cells in grid 
> choose a cell at random and call it CurrentCell 
> set VisitedCells = 1 
>
> while VisitedCells < TotalCells 
>
> find all neighbors of CurrentCell with all walls intact  
> if one or more found 
>     choose one at random 
>     knock down the wall between it and CurrentCell 
>     push CurrentCell location on the CellStack 
>     make the new cell CurrentCell 
>     add 1 to VisitedCells else 
>     pop the most recent cell entry off the CellStack 
>     make it CurrentCell endIf 
>
> endWhile
> ```

Im writing this in java, My problem is.

How should I be storing my visited cells, So that I can access them from reverse order of when I placed them in.

Like this?

```
List<Location> visitedCells = new ArrayList<Location>();

Then do I grab with visitedCells.get(visitedCells.size()-1)?
```

Location stores the x, y and z.
Not something Im trying to ask you.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) for this purpose:

```
Stack<Location> visitedCells = new Stack<Location>();
visitedCells.push(myLocation1);
visitedCells.push(myLocation2);

// Get last one in but DONT remove
Location location2 = visitedCells.peek(); 

// Get last one in and remove
location2 = visitedCells.pop();
```

Comment: I would post a link to how to use the Java Stack class and its general usage.

Answer (score 3):

The LIFO structure is best implemented in Java using a [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) object instead of `Stack`. The `Stack` class extends `Vector` and is only kept for backwards compatibility.

To use `Deque`, your best bet is to use `LinkedList`, which implements the `Deque` interface.

```
Deque<Location> locationStack = new LinkedList<Location>();
```

or `ArrayDeque`:

```
Deque<Location> locationStack = new ArrayDeque<Location>();
```

Then use the `push` and `pop` methods to push and pop `Location` objects.

The `Stack` class has a bunch of synchronization overhead that's more or less useless and only causes your code to slow down as it enters and exits synchronized code.

Comment: I can't grab items inside the middle of this can I.
Such as the last item entered does not meet my specifications.

Comment: Do you mean [random access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access) like a `List`? If you're trying to access the middle of a stack, then it's not really a stack. Is this part of the requirement, being able to access elements in the middle?

Comment: I've figured out what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Following code stores the values in the order you added.

```
List<Location> visitedCells = new ArrayList<Location>();
```

Then you can call

```
Collections.reverse(visitedCells);
```

gives you reverse ordered list.

(or)

You may use [ArrayDeque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html)

Comment: Why did you suggest this instead of a stack?

Comment: Agreed. A stack will give better performance and is better suited to what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Well, OP started with List. Otherwise we may go for ArrayDeque (Which is implementation of stack datastructure). Updated answer with link for ArrayDeque.

Comment: I think he started with a list because he isn't sure what to use.  Although your answer is valid is that is what the OP needs.